# Find the mathematical expectation and the dispersion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

We have an absolutely continuous random variable $X$ with $\mathbb E[X]=a$, $\mathbb D[X]=b^2$ and a probability distribution function $F(x)$.

The question is to find the mathematical expectation and the dispersion of the random variable $Z=-\log\big(1-F(X)\big)$.

Please, help!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed over $(0, 1)$. Then
\begin{align*}
E(Z) &= \int_0^1-\ln(1-x)dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \ln x dx =1,
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
Var(Z) &= \int_0^1 \ln^2(1-x)dx -1\\
&=\int_0^1\ln^2x dx-1 =1.
\end{align*}

Alternatively, note that $Z$ is an exponential random variable with distribution function $1-e^{-x}$, for $x>0$, and $0$, otherwise. We can obtain the same expectation and variance as above.